# How can i add several labels to a list in a for loop?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to be able to do something like this so that i can just add label then label1 label 2 label3 etc and i cant create an array of new labels or anything since my labels have an image attached to them and have to keep a certain position as well. So making a new label that has some text as a label that wont show up anywhere in particular on my form isn't much use.

```
List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    labels.Add(label + (i.ToString()));    
}
```

Comment: You need to add each label to the [Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collection on the form.

Comment: Winforms? WPF? Web?

Comment: You need to add the Labels also to the container's Controls collection and set a suitable Loacation, unless possibley the container is a FlowLayoutPanel..

Comment: Trying to get an object by its name (having the name as a String) is way more hard than the problem that you have by itself. I would recomend to access the lables from some colection where they already are in (Like the form.Controls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `Labels` to list from `Form` by name like this :

```
List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var label = 
        this.Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(lb => lb.Name == "label" + i).FirstOrDefault();
    if (label != null)
        labels.Add(label);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a Code Sample:**

You need to add the labels to the Controls collection of the tab page:

```
Page2.Controls.Add(CustomLabel[CustomLabel.Count - 1] as Control);

List<Label> customLabels = new List<Label>();

foreach (string ValutaCustomScelta in Properties.Settings.Default.ValuteCustom)
{
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(317, 119 + customLabels.Count*26);
    label.Parent = Page2;
    label.Name = "label" + ValutaCustomScelta;
    label.Text = ValutaCustomScelta;
    label.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(77, 21);
    customLabels.Add(label);
    Page2.Controls.Add(label);
}
```

Comment: @stuartd Edited the Answer

Comment: Which TabPage are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the labels by code or by design?

If you added them by code just add them then to the list.

If you added them by design there are two options. They are all on the same container (panel, form, groupbox...) or they are not.

If they are you can:

```
for each(control ctr in $yourcontainer.controls)
{
    if(ctr is Label)
    {
        labels.add(ctr);
    }
}
```

If they are not in the same container you can add them by hardcode

```
labels.add(%label1name);
labels.add(%label2name);
labels.add(%label3name);
labels.add(%label4name);
```

But if they are too much, you can run the code before for each one of the panels